# Unable to request session with fastlane spaceauth: Spaceship::AccessForbiddenError

Tags: ios, app-store, circleci, fastlane

I am trying to deploy iOS application automatically with `fastlane` under `CircleCI`. Unfortunately it wants 2-factor authentication. I am trying to do on my development machine:

```
fastlane spaceauth -u my@email.com
```

and it sends me code by mobile phone, i.e. password is correct and valid. Unfortunately, after I enter the code, it says me

```
Requesting session...
Could not login to App Store Connect
Please check your credentials and try again.
This could be an issue with App Store Connect,
Please try unsetting the FASTLANE_SESSION environment variable
(if it is set) and re-run `fastlane spaceauth`

Exception type: Spaceship::AccessForbiddenError
```

How to fix that?

Comment: did you fixed this?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/fastlane: /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.176.0/libexec/bin/fastlane: /usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/fastlane: line 4: /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.176.0/libexec/bin/fastlane: Undefined error: 0` I am getting this error after running cmd